# Smallest pitch 2 pin connector for WLC coil

Tags: power-electronics, wireless-charging

I am not sure if this is right forum but does any one knows the part number or component for connecting WLC coil to 2 pin on PCB.
WLC(Wire less charging coil) is for a wearable ( 1 A max current) . I am looking for a pitch ~ 0.5 or lesser mm but not sure if it will support the specification of 1A WLC coil.
The  last resort is to directly go with the soldering instead of some male-female connector.
please advise.

Comment: 0.5mm for a wire connector is challenging, mechanically. Why do you need it that small? Maybe we can help with a way around that need.

Comment: the closed i could find is 1.2 mm . Our solution is a small wearable and need  this form factor. what you suggest. soldering idea is the last thing on my mind.

Comment: I'd assume some potting including both the coil and the PCB would make that mechanically sound

Comment: sorry what is potting? can you illustrate this by posting some picture or link to picture.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potting_(electronics)